# pass None variables from function to function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have created a play and record function based on sounddevice playrec()

see : [python-sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/_modules/sounddevice.html#playrec)

They use the following method of inputparameters

```
def playrec(data, samplerate=None, channels=None, dtype=None,
            out=None, input_mapping=None, output_mapping=None, blocking=False,
            **kwargs):
```

so i want do the same and pass some variables thru to the default functions
like:

```
import numpy as np
T = 10
fs = 44100
t =  np.arange(10*fs)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi* 440*t) + 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi* 880*t) + 0.25 * np.sin(2*np.pi* 1320*t)

rec1 = customplayrec(x.T, fs, input_channels=2, output_channels=2, repeats=3)

def customplayrec(data, samplerate=None, input_channels=None, output_channels=None,
           repeats=None, l0=None, cascade=False, dtype=None, out=None,
           input_mapping=None, output_mapping=None, blocking=False, **kwargs):
    import sounddevice as sd  
    #... filter some variables
    record = sd.playrec(data, samplerate, input_channels, dtype, out,
                        input_mapping, output_mapping, blocking, kwargs)
    #... do something with data...
    return(record)
```

The result is that this function breaks (it don't play and record any sound ).
I don't get an error... So i have tested where i breaks and i found out. one line before the function starts everything works fine.
Also spyder don't show the variables who are `None`.
So I think that it have to do with passing the input values thru.

How can i pass these variables thru if they are not empty.

- method or module

If a similar question all ready excist i searched but don't know the right keywords...

Thanks in advance

Comment: All you've done is define a function. What is the issue or what do you mean by "breaks"?

Comment: it don't play/ record sound - it does nothing.

Comment: Well, how did you call the function? You provided link to some source code, but not a [mcve]

Comment: The example should work now.

Comment: @Jan-Bert the code that you've posted looks like it should work great. If it doesn't record sound (or indeed do anything at all) it's because you haven't posted where you actually CALL the function at any point. I'm therefore assuming that you don't call any function, which is why it doesn't work. cricket_007 mentioned that a couple of times, but I haven't seen you address those concerns yet.

Comment: @AdamSmith for testing i used the debug function in spyder and a print line 1 line before calling the function. The line were printed in the console but no audio output and no recorded sound

Comment: As mentioned already by cricket_007, you haven't provided an MCVE so there's no way for anyone but you to test whether or not it works. We have to take you at your word that it does (or doesn't), but that makes it all but impossible to debug. If you can edit your question to contain ***verifiable*** code, that's one thing, but otherwise this question is off-topic.

Comment: I don't think that is the error - at least it is another bug: When you call `sd.playrec`, the last argument should be `**kwargs`, not just `kwargs`. Well with a bit of luck, that is actually the problem.

Comment: Also: Is `x` meant to be the wave-data? Shouldn't you multiply in the time variable into the trigonometric functions?

Comment: Oke was forgotten the time. I have just 5 scripts and have now just add everythin in 10 lines... The time is not the problem there is another function for. about the kwargs... i get an dictionary kwargs to me it is most logic to pass the hole dictionary thru... since that is empty it shouldn't complain about that.

Comment: I agree it might not be the problem, but if you pass `kwargs` without `**`, it will be appended, if empty, as an empty dictionary and not as nothing. That is a change in signature and might break something with the function call. But I assume you have tested by now with and without `**`

Comment: oke i tried and still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments it looks the method used in my scripts are not wrong... it could be a problem related to python-sounddevice.
At the github page of python-sounddevice i saw that there is possible an related issue about the same topic...
see [sounddevice issue 38](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/38)
So at this moment I can't get further but at least i have an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Let me formulate my comments as an answer (with reservations, as I cannot test your code):

1. Make sure your data is actually a wave and not just an array of constant
   values. I suspect you forgot to include `t` into the arguments of the   trigonometric functions.
2. The last argument of the `sd.playrc` call should be `**kwargs`, not just `kwargs`.